# Cordova/Phonegap multipart-form based login to external service

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, basic-authentication

Im using Ionic Framework for this.

I'm trying to automate access to a device I have.  The device requires the user to log in via a form that is similar to:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" method="post" action="http://IP/login.cgi">
```

...

```
<td><label for="username">Username:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>

<td><label for="password">Username:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></td>
```

Once succesfully authenticated, the device exposes some JSONP api that I can use.

The issue I have is figuring out how best to perform this login automatically.  I can recreate the login form in a template and when submit but this redirects if successful away from the app.  My other idea was to use the inAppBrowserPlugin but I hit the CORS problem with the error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any ideas appreciated.

J

Answer (score 1):

CORS isn't a problem once your app is installed on a device. Once your code is built do a device, it allows all origins by default.

CORS is a problem, however, while you build out your app in the browser. There are two ways to fix it though:

**Hard:**
Configure your angular application to run everything through a proxy, then set up a proxy server locally with Node.
http://ionicframework.com/blog/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

**Easy**
Install a chrome extension that will do the proxying for you. I use this not only with Ionic, but all the time while developing with APIs I don't control. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: I realised this later last evening.  The problem now is that XHR requests do not send cookies from what I can tell?  I can authenticate against the web interface via an iframe or inAppBrowser, but when I call the end point that serves back JSON the $http does not send the cookie with the auth token.  I have this vaguely 'working' via an iframe where I can after authentication ask the iframe to load the API and read the contents back to the ionic app.  Obviously this is not a nice solution.

Comment: You can send whatever custom data you want with an http request. here is the $http doc:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http